# How to do indentation in Latex (Beginner question)

Tags: formatting

How can I write the following in Latex:

```
We want to study: X -> Y            
                  x -> f(x)
```

Also if there is any Latex book that you recommend for me, I would like you if you suggest it.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11) should be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your preamble (if not already done):

```
\usepackage{amsmath} %% or, better, the mathtools extension)
```

and this line in the body of your document:

```
We want to study $\begin{aligned}[t]f\colon X & \longrightarrow Y\\ x&\longmapsto f(x) \end{aligned} $
```

[image]